# How to get the documentation comment as string

Tags: rust

I'm a rookie rust language user

I'm curious is it possible to get the document comment on the code?

```rust
enum Foo {
    #[doc = "I want this string"]
    Bar,
    /// or this one
    Baz,
}
```

---

(edited)

I'm trying to build an `enum` for the response code definition and add a brief description to it.

```rust
enum CodeDefinition {
    /// Internal error. Please contact the administrator
    Unknown,
}

impl std::fmt::Display for CodeDefinition {
    #[inline]
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        match self {
            Self::Unknown => write!(f, "Internal error. Please contact the administrator"),
        }
    }
}
```

The brief description will be written twice in the code, so I started to find a way to avoid this.

Comment: I don't think so, it gets stripped out by the compiler and only gets used by the docs generator.

Comment: Might be relevant: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/assign-a-doc-comment-to-a-string-literal/74888/9

Comment: It's a strange requirement.  Especially since you're a rookie rustacean,  perhaps this is an X/Y problem?  If you explain *why* you want to do this, there may well be a better/more idiomatic Rusty way of solving the underlying problem.

Comment: @eggyal I agree, might be an X/Y problem which actually requires [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html)

Comment: Thank your kind response! and thank @eggyal for reminding me I should explain my case. My use case is very close to Finomnis's comment, I will provide some additional info for my quest

Comment: Maybe you should define these messages as constants, and use them both in the doc and in the `write!` call.

Comment: @BlackBeans: while you can *reference* a `const` in the docs, you won't be able to include its evaluated value (doc comments are just macros, which are expanded before const eval).

Comment: There's probably some crate that provides a macro for this...  ah yes, [displaydoc](https://crates.io/crates/displaydoc)?

Comment: I feel like your actual usecase here is error enums. For that, I'd wholeheartedly recommend the [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror/latest/thiserror/) crate, it's the standard go-to for error enums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your second code example, I deduct that you are trying to write an error enum.

For that, (at the time of writing) the defacto go-to library is [thiserror](https://docs.rs/thiserror):

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
enum CodeDefinition {
    /// Internal error
    #[error("Internal error. Please contact the administrator")]
    Unknown,
}

fn main() {
    let err = CodeDefinition::Unknown;
    println!("Display:  {}", err);
    println!("Debug:    {:?}", err);
}
```

```
Display:  Internal error. Please contact the administrator
Debug:    Unknown
```

---

This also implements the [`std::error::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) trait for your enum, which is very useful when interacting with other libraries.

For example, in conjunction with error wrapper libraries like [anyhow](https://docs.rs/anyhow) or [miette](https://docs.rs/miette):

`anyhow` example:

```rust
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug)]
enum CodeDefinition {
    /// Internal error
    #[error("Internal error. Please contact the administrator")]
    Unknown,
}

fn failing_function() -> Result<(), CodeDefinition> {
    Err(CodeDefinition::Unknown)
}

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    failing_function()?;

    Ok(())
}
```

```
Error: Internal error. Please contact the administrator
```

---

`miette` example.

A little more complex, but demonstrates that `thiserror` can also be used to tag the `source` of an error:

```rust
use miette::Diagnostic;
use thiserror::Error;

#[derive(Error, Debug, Diagnostic)]
enum DivisionError {
    #[error("Cannot divide through zero")]
    DivisionThroughZero,
}

#[derive(Error, Debug, Diagnostic)]
enum MyGreatAlgorithmError {
    #[error("Division failed")]
    DivisionFailed(#[source] DivisionError),
}

fn divide(a: i32, b: i32) -> Result<i32, DivisionError> {
    if b != 0 {
        Ok(a / b)
    } else {
        Err(DivisionError::DivisionThroughZero)
    }
}

fn my_great_algorithm() -> Result<i32, MyGreatAlgorithmError> {
    let value = divide(9001, 0).map_err(|e| MyGreatAlgorithmError::DivisionFailed(e))?;
    Ok(value)
}

fn main() -> miette::Result<()> {
    let value = my_great_algorithm()?;
    println!("{}", value);

    Ok(())
}
```

```
Error: 
  × Division failed
  ╰─▶ Cannot divide through zero
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into a related need today, although in my case what I wanted is a type's outer doc comment, not the doc comments on an enum's variants. In case you are curious, I wanted it for OpenAPI documentation generation using [utoipa](https://github.com/juhaku/utoipa).

I asked around but it seems like there exists no well-established crate for this. There is [bevy_reflect](https://crates.io/crates/bevy_reflect), but it's too heavy-weight for my needs. So I built my own little crate just for this: [documented](https://crates.io/crates/documented).

Here's an example:

```rust
use documented::Documented;

/// 69
#[derive(Documented)]
struct Nice;

assert_eq!(Nice::DOCS, "69");
```

---

Edit:

In 0.2.0 this crate now supports doc comments on struct members and enum variants too via [`documented::DocumentedFields`](https://docs.rs/documented/0.2.0/documented/trait.DocumentedFields.html).